# EE3 Extension not showing up - what am I missing?

Tags: extension

I've read this:

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/conversion/index.html

and this:

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/extensions.html

I have a folder called:

`ee/system/user/addons/ldap_plugin`

in this folder I have:

```
addon.setup.php
ext.ldap_plugin.php
language/
```

`addon.setup.php` looks like:

```
<?php

return array(
  'author'      => 'Me',
  'author_url'  => 'http://example.com/',
  'name'        => 'Ldap Plugin',
  'description' => 'Handles LDAP login / account creation',
  'version'     => '1.0.0',
  'namespace'   => 'Ldap_plugin\Ldap_plugin',
  'settings_exist' => TRUE
);
```

`ext.ldap_plugin.php` contains:

```
class Ldap_plugin_ext {
    var $settings       = array();
    var $name           = 'LDAP Plugin';
    var $version        = '1.0.0';
    var $description    = 'Handles LDAP login / account creation';
    var $settings_exist = 'y';
    var $docs_url       = '';
    var $debug          = TRUE;

    function __construct($settings='')
    {
        $this->EE =& get_instance();
        $this->settings = $settings;
    }

    function activate_extension ()
    {
        /*.....*/
    }

    function update_extension($current = '')
    {
        /*.....*/
    }

    function disable_extension()
    {
        /*.....*/
    }

    function settings()
    {
        /*.....*/
    }

    /* various hooks here*/
}
```

and yet, it will *not* show up in `Developer / Add-On Manager` for installation. I have other 3rd party add-ons that show up. I've removed them and renamed them and they properly respond, so I know the folder is being seen in the right place. I've checked file permissions on the above folders and they match the other add-ons.

I'm not seeing the issue here. Do Extensions get managed elsewhere? Is there something critical I'm missing that's required?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: All your code above is Fine. I Just copied it and addon is showing in my backend. http://prntscr.com/e5o3kd . I suggest you to delete and recreate the files again. Maybe you are forgetting something.

Comment: You're spot on. We are migrating to EE3 and I didn't realize in the config that `$env_config['allow_extensions']` was set to `n`. Once I turned this on and cleared out some old DB entries in `exp_extensions` it showed right up! Thanks for verifying I wasn't crazy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that two things were wrong:

1. In the `config.master.php` file, `$env_config['allow_extensions']` was set to `n` and should be set to `y`
2. This is a migration and had some old entries in `exp_extensions` table in the database for extensions we no longer had installed. Once I turned on `allow_extensions` I had to clear those out in that table. It showed right up then!